# Error deploying Rails 4 App to Heroku redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, redis

I have like a year deploying my rails app in heroku without problem but recently when I try to push the app it just crashes. I tested it using heroku local and it works but on heroku it doesnt.

I didn't change anything on the conf files it just suddenly do not work on heroku

```
Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
[4] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[4] * Version 3.11.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Love Song
[4] * Min threads: 2, max threads: 2
[4] * Environment: production
[4] * Process workers: 1
[4] * Preloading application
[4] ! Unable to load application: Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma)
Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:344:in `rescue in establish_connection'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:329:in `establish_connection'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:99:in `block in connect'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:291:in `with_reconnect'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:98:in `connect'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:363:in `ensure_connected'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:219:in `block in process'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:304:in `logging'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:218:in `process'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:118:in `call'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:1423:in `block in smembers'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:45:in `block in synchronize'
   /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:45:in `synchronize'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-4.0.1/lib/redis.rb:1422:in `smembers'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.6.0/lib/redis/namespace.rb:442:in `call_with_namespace'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.6.0/lib/redis/namespace.rb:328:in `method_missing'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/resque-1.27.4/lib/resque/data_store.rb:236:in `worker_ids'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/resque-1.27.4/lib/resque/worker.rb:72:in `all'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/resque-1.27.4/lib/resque.rb:464:in `workers'
   /app/config/application.rb:44:in `<class:Application>'
   /app/config/application.rb:13:in `<module:Truckbu>'
   /app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
   /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
   /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
   config.ru:3:in `require'
   config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
   config.ru:in `new'
   config.ru:in `<main>'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:318:in `load_rackup'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:243:in `app'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:138:in `load_and_bind'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/cluster.rb:397:in `run'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:183:in `run'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:77:in `run'
   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
  /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/puma:23:in `<top (required)>'
 State changed from starting to crashed
 Process exited with status 1
```

The redis url is set in ENV as usual.

Comment: And did you configure a local Redis URL or to an external service?

Comment: @spickermann what do you mean? On heroku it should pick the URL from REDIS_URL config var but for some reason it isnt working now.

Comment: I ask you to confirm that you configured a `REDIS_URL` in the Heroku settings and that its value is not `localhost`. How does line `44` in your `config/application.rb` look like?

Comment: @spickermann REDIS_URL =     redis://h:pc12cd8797ab46f3xxxx@ec2-34-227-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:54419

config/application.rb 44 = Resque.workers.each {|w| w.unregister_worker}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could find the problem and it was that the project is configured to work with Redis 3.3.5. They updated the gem and then the configuration changed. I solved it by setting the gem version that work with the current configuration in the Gemfile.